# ListView ArrayAdapter filtering by two names

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have done an application for android to list contact with first name equals for example John. But I need view contact with `name1` OR `name2`, for example `Peter OR John`.

I have tried set filter "`Peter OR John`", "`Peter || John`", but it does not work. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Show your code to be able to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

```
    you should be write your custom adapter and filter. 



    public class MyAdapter<T extends BaseEntity> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements Filterable{

        private MainClass.ObjectFilter filter;
        private final List<T> objects;

        public MyAdapter(List<T> objects){
             enter code here
this.objects = objects;
             getFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (filter == null){
                MainClass ofc = new MainClass(objects);
                filter  = ofc.getObjectFilter();
            }
            return filter;
        }

        enter code here 
    }


    and custom filter


    public class MainClass<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseEntity {

        private List<T> allObjectItemsArray; // all contact list
        private List<T> filteredObjectItemsArray; // filtered contact list

        public ObjectFilterMainClass(List<T> objects)
          {
            this.allObjectItemsArray = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.allObjectItemsArray.addAll(objects);
            this.filteredObjectItemsArray = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.filteredObjectItemsArray.addAll(allObjectItemsArray);
        }

        public ObjectFilter getObjectFilter(){
        return new ObjectFilter();
        }


        public class ObjectFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // constraint search text -->  Peter OR John
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<T> filteredItems = new ArrayList<T>();

            a: for (int i = 0; i < allObjectItemsArray.size(); i++) {
                T m = allObjectItemsArray.get(i);
                        // cast m to your class
                String fistnameAndLastName = ((your object class) m).getFirstName() + ((your object class) m).getLastName();

                if (fistnameAndLastName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    filteredItems.add(m);
                    continue a;
                }

            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = allObjectItemsArray;
                result.count = allObjectItemsArray.size();
            }
            }
            return result;
        }

          @Override
        public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filteredObjectItemsArray = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.clear();
            if (filteredObjectItemsArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < filteredObjectItemsArray.size(); i++)
                adapter.add(filteredObjectItemsArray.get(i));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

        }

    }

    main point is get first and last name and check the constraint text.
    after that if true add filteredItems list.

    String fistnameAndLastName = ((your object class) m).getFirstName() + ((your object class) m).getLastName();

    if (fistnameAndLastName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) 
    {
        filteredItems.add(m);
        continue a;


    and use :

    EditText edt = (EditText) this.view.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtName);

            edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                addFilterToList();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
            }); 

    public void addFilterToList() {

        ListView listView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        EditText edt = (EditText) this.view.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtName);

        MyAdapter myA = (MyAdapter) //
            (listView.getAdapter());  

        myA.getFilter().filter(edt.getText());

        listView.setAdapter(myA);
        }
```